# Zoomcharts export as image

Tags: zoomcharts

I'm trying to export an zoomcharts network to an image. From https://zoomcharts.com/developers/en/net-chart/chart-basics/export/ I understood that this is the minimal code:

```
function exportImg(){
    chart.saveAsImage("png");
}
```

Does the default proxy server provide a download link? The page to above also provides a link to "learn how to enable/disable export button in toolbar" but I can't find that info..

Answer (score 1):

The implementation lags a bit behind the implementation. The minimal code actually is:

```
chart.saveAsImage("png", {});
```

This will return a urlencoded image.

To initiate image download, call

```
chart.export("png", {});
```

It works by submitting the image data as a POST request to our development proxy. If you are planning to have high bandwidth, please consider rolling your own proxy.
The development proxy does not provide download links, just responds to the post request.

Export toolbar button for Network chart is still in development. Check the TimeChart demo to see how it will work.